# Discord Bot Kick Command

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

how i can set kick command with a role use just that Moderator role will can use
my kick command :

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
async def kick(ctx, userName: discord.User):
    """Kick A User from server"""
    await client.kick(userName)
    await client.say("__**Successfully User Has Been Kicked!**__")
```

Comment: Please articulate your problem more clearly.

Comment: Read the discord py documentation, look for something in the lines of administrator privileges in channel

Comment: Discord.py documentation doesn't cover commands.ext. You have to look at the github repo to learn about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`commands.has_permissions`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L838) decorator to ensure the caller has a specific permission.

```
@client.command(...)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, ...):
    pass
```

Just a word of warning though, according to the function docstring, it checks for the user having *any* required permission instead of *all*.
It is also recommended to add the [`bot_has_permissions`](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/async/discord/ext/commands/core.py#L896) check too to make sure it can actually kick users too.